# Can't use mkdir in NPM script from Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to have a script that looks like this:

```
{
    "scripts":
        "setup": "mkdir -p ./my-dir"
}
```

And it fails, at least on Windows, even if I run it from a Git Bash prompt. Even trying just `mkdir ./my-dir` doesn't work. I can't figure out any reason it should fail.

The error it gives is a "syntax incorrect" error:

```
> my-app@0.0.1 stage C:\my-app
> mkdir ./my-dir

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "stage"
npm ERR! node v6.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.1 stage: `mkdir ./my-dir`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.1 stage script 'mkdir ./my-dir'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mkdir ./my-dir
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\my-app\npm-debug.log
```

If this won't work, is there a cross-platform friendly way to initialize an empty directory?

Comment: can you paste the error message that you have?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Should be `npm setup`

Comment: Added the error message. I'm using `npm run setup`. My actual command isn't named setup,, that was just an example.

Comment: Well explained here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12774

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This module possibly will solve your problem:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp

Comment: Had to install the package globally (npm i -g mkdirp) to be able to use 'mkdirp dist/js -p' on Windows. But yeah it works :)

Comment: Just a heads up, it's possible to install it locally, you just have to use `./node_modules/.bin/mkdirp` instead of just `mkdirp` from the locally installed folder. Holds true for pretty much all NPM commands.

Comment: You don't have to prefix `./node_modules/.bin/`because `npm` already adds this path to PATH. Reference: [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

Comment: I just noticed the last comment and wanted to add some clarification since it still gets a fair number of views. If you are using `mkdirp` (or any bin command) from an npm script (in your `package.json`, you don't need anything but the command. If you want to call it directly in your terminal, you either need `./node_modules/.bin/mkdirp` or install it with the `-g` flag. This was a case where everyone was right. =)

Comment: To note, now you can just do `npx mkdirp` instead of the directory path if you want to run it directly. If you run it as apart of an NPM script, it's still the same as my above comment.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [**npx**](https://medium.com/@maybekatz/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner-55f7d4bd282b) *plus* [**mkdirp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp) for a relatively lightweight, portable solution without global installs

Add this to `package.json`:

```js
"scripts": {
  "create-dir": "npx mkdirp _site/assets",
}
```

And then use like this:

```sh
$ npm run create-dir
```

Answer (score 12):

Npm is using the windows mkdir command, not the linux. Use

```
"setup": "mkdir .\\my-dir"
```

Use backslashes.

You can also install cygwin and run:

```
/cygwin64/bin/mkdir -p mydir
```

Comment: This works on a windows computer running the npm command on a bash terminal, but not with the `-p`

Comment: A proper solution without adding an extra package. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When executing a command on Windows instead of using its version of `mkdir`, I use Git Bash and set it as the default shell in npm:

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't need double backslashes.  Single backslashes. will do.